# How can I extract the difference from two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server.

I have one query which outputs results, and another that does the same. Id like to output what the is not in the other:

```
select distinct 
v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0
from v_GS_PC_BIOS
JOIN v_R_System ON v_R_System.ResourceID  = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
WHERE v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID NOT IN 
(
    SELECT distinct v_R_System.ResourceID from v_r_system
)
```

**OR**

```
Select distinct
v_R_System.ResourceID
from v_R_System
WHERE v_R_System.ResourceID NOT IN 
(
    select distinct 
    v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0
    from v_GS_PC_BIOS
    JOIN v_R_System ON v_R_System.ResourceID  = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
)
```

I am getting 0 results

Comment: [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: or Right Join - Union all - Left join. <-- this way you can add fake column `fromwhere` and hard-code `from right` or `from left`

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @Dale K  I Though EXCEPT had to have the same amount and type of columns

Comment: @T.S. Is there an example on that somewhere?

Comment: @My9to5 your question is only selecting a single column per query? The reason your query is not working is probably due to the value `NULL` appearing in the inner resultset, `NOT IN (NULL)` returns nothing. If you exclude nulls from the inner query I expect it will work. i.e.  `SELECT v_R_System.ResourceID FROM v_r_system WHERE v_R_System.ResourceID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @My9to5 see my answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to compare table contents

Lets say you have 2 tables

`Cars: modelid, manufacturerid, ... some more car related columns`

`Airplanes: modelid, manufacturerid, ... some more airplane related columns`

**Task:** determine, which car manufacturers **don't** make airplanes, and vise-versa.

```sql
SELECT c.manufacturerName, 'only cars' as specialization
FROM cars c LEFT JOIN
     airplanes a ON c.manufacturerid = a.manufacturerid
WHERE a.manufacturerid IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT a.manufacturerName, 'only airplanes' as specialization
FROM cars c RIGHT JOIN
     airplanes a ON c.manufacturerid = a.manufacturerid
WHERE c.manufacturerid IS NULL
```

Results here should be like

> Mazda, only cars
> Toyota, only cars
> Airbus, only airplanes

And companies like these **should not show** because their record will be in both tables

> Honda, Mitsubishi, Saab, Ford, Fiat

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the explanation

Comment: @My9to5 If this answer is solving your problem, please accept and upvote. Thank you

Comment: I dont think I can because it says I dont have enough reputation

Comment: @My9to5 do you have enough now?